# Brute forcing Project Euler Problem 27

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

[Problem 27](https://projecteuler.net/problem=27)
The Goal of the problem is to find the quadratic (n^2+an+b) that can generate the most consecutive primes, such that |a|<1000 and |b|<1001

So I decided to brute force it using python. However, the script I wrote it quite slow. What did I do wrong and how can I improve it?

```
primes=[] #prime list
prime_multiples = set()
for i in range(2, 3000000):
    if i not in prime_multiples:
        primes.append(i)
        prime_multiples.update(range(i, 3000000, i))

bm=-1000
n=0
am=-999
count=40

a=-999
while a<=999:
    b=1
    while b<=1000 :
        n=0
        n_c=1
        while n_c==1 :
            attemp = n**2 +a*n +b
            if all(-i**2 -i*a<=b for i in range(0, 40)) and b in primes:
                if attemp in primes:
                    n+=1
                    if n>=count:
                        count=n
                        am=a
                        bm=b
                        prod=am*bm
                        print(f"a={am} with b={bm} gave {count} consecutive primes")
                        print(f"the pruduct is {prod}")
                else:
                    n_c=2
            else:
                n_c=2
        b+=1
    a+=1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> primes=[] #prime list
> prime_multiples = set()
> for i in range(2, 3000000):
>     if i not in prime_multiples:
>         primes.append(i)
>         prime_multiples.update(range(i, 3000000, i))
> ```

It's conventional to do the sieve of Eratosthenes with an array of booleans, not a set. You probably get better cache coherence that way, and you can do fast checks afterwards whether something is a prime. `in` checks against a list are *slow*, because they are *linear*.

---

> ```
> bm=-1000
> n=0
> am=-999
> ```

What purpose do these variables serve?

---

> ```
> a=-999
> while a<=999:
>     ....
>     a+=1
> ```

The Pythonic approach would be

```
for a in range(-999, 1000):
```

---

> ```
>         n=0
>         n_c=1
>         while n_c==1 :
>             attemp = n**2 +a*n +b
>             if all(-i**2 -i*a<=b for i in range(0, 40)) and b in primes:
>                 if attemp in primes:
>                     n+=1
>                     if n>=count:
>                         count=n
>                         am=a
>                         bm=b
>                         prod=am*bm
>                         print(f"a={am} with b={bm} gave {count} consecutive primes")
>                         print(f"the pruduct is {prod}")
>                 else:
>                     n_c=2
>             else:
>                 n_c=2
> ```

What is this code doing? The task (which, as an aside, it would have been very helpful to find in the question alongside the code) is

> Considering quadratics of the form: \$n^2+an+b\$, where \$|a|<1000\$ and \$|b|\le 1000\$ find the product of the coefficients, \$a\$ and \$b\$, for the quadratic expression that produces the maximum number of primes for consecutive values of \$n\$, starting with \$n=0\$.

So what I would expect to find in the loop is a simple count: what is the largest \$n\$ for which the quadratic gives a prime? Instead there are nested loops and control flow which looks like it's from the 50s, from a language which doesn't have subroutines. Consider

```
n = next(iter(i for i in itertools.count() if (i**2 + a*i + b) not in primes))
if n > count:
    count = n
    printf(f"a={a} with b={b} gave {count} consecutive primes with product {a*b}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `while n_c == 1:` loop, is `b` constant?  If `b in primes` is false, does it make sense to even bother entering the `while n_c == 1:` loop?  And if it is prime before entering the loop, does it make sense to test if it is true every iteration of that loop?  Avoid wasting time by moving invariant expressions and conditions out of loops!

Your first two while loops would be better written as `for variable in range(lower_limit, upper_limit+1):`